# Calling method several times that uses System.Timers.Timer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I had no idea how to create this post with a good title, so I apologize beforehand.

I use `System.Timers.Timer` in the following method to pause for a certain amount of time. Essentially I instantiate the class only once and then call the following method TestDelay() several times with different Double values.

The problem with instantiating ToErase once, but calling `TestDelay()` twice, is that the delay is not made. On the other hand, if I instantiate class ToErase twice and call `TestDelay()` once per each instance, then the delay is made. I assume it's due to private property Delay, which is shared within the same instance.

My question, how would I need to modify this class so that I can instantiate ToErase only once and call TestDelay() several times?

I considered `Thread.Sleep()`, but it sleeps the whole console application, including any other instances of `TestDelay()` that may be running at the moment.

Here's my code:

```
class ToErase
{
    private System.Timers.Timer Delay;
    private ManualResetEventSlim ev = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    public void TestDelay(Double ms)
    {

        Console.Write(".");

        ev = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

        //TimeSpan span = DateTimeRun.AddMinutes(Offset).Subtract(now);
        Delay = new System.Timers.Timer(ms);
        Delay.Enabled = true;

        Delay = new System.Timers.Timer(ms);
        Delay.Elapsed += Delay_Elapsed;
        Delay.Enabled = true;
        while (Delay.Enabled)
        {
            string s = "";
            ////Wait until time passes
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Timer completed for QTR");
    }
    private void Delay_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Delay.Enabled = false;
        ev.Set();
    }

}
```

Comment: How does this code _not_ do the same thing as `Thread.Sleep()`? The method `TestDelay()` doesn't return until your timer expires, which is the same behavior `Thread.Sleep()` has. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on characteristics of a _good_ code example.

Comment: Because the code you posted doesn't make any sense, and no one can tell what problem you're actually trying to solve here. Pretend you know _nothing_ about the code you're working on, and put yourself in the shoes of the people reading your question. If you make an honest assessment of your own question, you'll understand why you got down-voted.

Comment: It's unlikely anyone down-voted you "just to make a point". Down-voting on SO has genuine meaning and practical reasons for happening; it's not simply a mechanism for people to express their opinion (though that may be one side-effect). You should take care to not make assumptions about the motivations of others. And maybe you should spend your time more productively; it would be better to stay focused on improving your question, than to complain about the community's reaction to your question.

Comment: And you make that claim based on, what exactly? Do you understand the down-voting mechanism? Do you know why it exists? Do you think you are the final arbiter as to who should use the down-vote and who should not? Hint: the down-vote exists as a way of communicating between people who have read your question and those who may in the future. It's not about you and it's silly for you to make any claims as to whether you should have been down-voted or not. If you don't want the down-vote, write a good question. As a bonus: doing so will improve the odds that you'd get a useful answer.

Comment: @rbhatup - Peter is correct - the downvoting system is not personal or vindictive - it just exists to rate the quality of questions. Improve your question and maybe the downvotes go away. If you end up being "bitten" on this question then maybe the experience will lead to a better quality question next time. Go compare the quality of "Yahoo! Answers" to SO and you'll see the system is quite effective.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of things wrong with that class.  I assume you are new to OO programming.

Thread.Sleep is what you want.  There's no reason to write your own function.

You say that Thread.Sleep() "sleeps the whole console application."  If you get your class working, it will also delay "the whole console application" but it will be worse, because it will be spinning the processor the entire time.

The wording in your question makes me suspect your are working with multiple threads.  If you observe that Thread.Sleep pauses the main thread, but TestDelay does not, the reason is probably in the way you are calling the different functions.

Finally, If you are new to programming, I'd strongly suggest you avoid multi-threaded code for now.